# How to center image after hovering with both picture

Tags: html, css

Hello I need to center an image in css after hovering but both pictures (original and centered) need to be visible. Here's my current code:

**HTML**

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stajl.css"> 
</head>
<body> 
  <div>
    <img src="smile.jpeg">
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
div:hover { 
  text-align:center 
}
```

Thank you mates

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far..

Comment: HTML : <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stajl.css">
</head>
<body> 
<div>
<img src="smile.jpeg">
</div>
 </body>
CSS: div:hover {
 text-align:center
}

Comment: Now you'll need to clarify what you mean by both pictures, as there's only one image on the page and no reference in CSS.

Comment: As both pictures I mean that when I hover over the picture the centered  version of it will appear on the center of screen and the image that I hover over won't dissapear. Like hover to zoom feature.

Comment: Where is the another image?

Comment: I need something like lighbox method. There is one image (thumbnail) after hovering it should scale up and be centered

Answer (score 0):

This will take JS, keep in mind this JS code is just a very quick example and i will optimize it later on, we could cache the img sources and use a function with argument to not repeat code etc. But it works and is plain JS and kep as simple as possible for explanation purposes.

```
document.getElementById("left").addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
var placeholder = document.getElementById("imageHolder");

placeholder.style.background =  "url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nightlife)";
placeholder.style.opacity = 1;
```

});

This listens for a mouseover event on the image and on hover, it gets the placeholder div and puts the url value of the hovered img as background of the placeholder div.
The animation happens by changing the CSS opacity with a transition.

Link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/NrPrEL

Comment: Could it be done in CSS? It's for my school project and teacher said it must be done in CSS. Thanks anyway. I've also made some research and I need something like lightbox but done in CSS and with hover effect.

Comment: I've done this so far I only need effect to work after hovering, not clicking.

Comment: With css you are limited to only one image, can't think of a way to do this to more than one pic without css, except with an approach which would be very verbose. You could set 2 divs with same background but the opacity values to 0 and 1,then on hover, set the opacity of the hidden div to 1.But JS is the best approach for this imo

Comment: My example is on hover, unless you are on a mobile device.

Comment: One image will be ok

Comment: I mean like this effect but with hover instead of clicking http://codepen.io/ankldolan/pen/Eyagev